# Windows Phone 7 : FileStream exception

Tags: exception, windows-phone-7, filestream

I try to use FileStream (using namespace System.IO) but I get an exception :

```
Attempt to access the method failed
```

Here is the code :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

I searched on microsoft.com and I found that this error is because I use a bad library reference.

But in my project, I compile with mscorlib.dll from folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0

I need some help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), for example:

Place at the top of your file:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

Then in your method do this:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var istream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("File.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(istream))
        {
            sw.Write("Some Stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

A great example and explanation of this and other operations can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154(v=VS.95).aspx#Y300

You can look through your IsolatedStorage by using the [Windows Phone 7 IsolatedStorageExplorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/)

A good place to start for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff626516(v=VS.92).aspx

Also here: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/documentation

Comment: Thank you, it works. Have you got a link where I can find all functions available for windows phone sdk ? Because, when I try to use a .NET 4 function, sometimes, it's not available on windows phone 7

Comment: Another question, is it possible to view file created in storage from my computer ?

Comment: @TheFrancisOne I have added links in my answer that should help

Answer (score 1):

On WindowsPhone you must use IsolatedStorage - see this tutorial for example - http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/isolated-storage-on-wp7-ii/

Read:

```
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, store))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Write:

```
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, store))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }
```