# how to populate a listbox with files in the project of my windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

i want to use a listbox in my wp7 app where i want to display the names of all the files present in a specific directory. i have added the folder with all files in my project itself. i want to populate all the file names in that folder. how can i access it?
i am using this to bindlist

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\sony\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\MyChristmas\\MyChristmas\\recipe");
          foreach (string f in files)
            {
                string entry1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(f);
                string entry = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f);
                listBox1.Items.Add(entry);
}
```

it may be very basic but i am a student and am learning it all on my own so please help.

Comment: i used the same code as you did, and it worked for me. do you get any errors?

Comment: am i having problems with access permissions. how can i set it right. Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.String)

Comment: i just relized you are using WP7. i think you need to use isolatedSotrage to get files from the computer. in this question he get the same error. check it mybee it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234035/windows-phone-7-filestream-exception

Comment: Vivek,  what files are you trying to list?  on WP7 you will not have access to a Desktop filesystem like the path you mentioned about (c:\\users\\blabla).  WP7 has access to IsolatedStorage on the device, but that is limited to a few area for obvious security reasons.

Comment: i have included some files in my project. I have made a folder in my project an added files to it. i want to list text from these files itself. suppose i have a recipe app and have saved the recipes in different text files. now i want to list the recipes when the user runs the application. can someone help

Comment: Try reading this article - http://rahulpnath.com/blog/windows-phone-series-preloading-content/ This is what you are looking for...