# Simply get files from internal project folder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to populate a listbox with files in the project of my windows phone 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824721/how-to-populate-a-listbox-with-files-in-the-project-of-my-windows-phone-7-applic)

I'm a newbie on C# and this is annoying me a lot.

My application load a set of images from a folder that I simply created on the Solution Explorer called `Images`. I can see these images if I use it hardcoded with URIs and stuff, but what I want to do is to take these images names dinamycally and then load it. I have seen some questions like it but couldnt solve my problem. I'm trying like this:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"/Images");
foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()) {
      photos.Add(new Photo() { FileName = file.FullName, PhotoSource = GetImageSource("Images/" + file.FullName) });
}
```

The `directoryInfo` is always set as null. My project hierarchy as shown in Solution Explorer is like:

```
 Project
     Main.xaml
         Maim.xaml.cs
     Images
         1.jpg
         2.jpg
         ...
```

Thanks in any help.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> For a Windows Phone application, all I/O operations are restricted to
>   isolated storage and do not have direct access to the underlying
>   operating system file system or to the isolated storage of other
>   applications.

So you can't access your Images folder in the manner you'd like.

Since you can't add images dynamically to your XAP anyway, the images available will be constant. It appears you will just have to add the URIs manually:

`BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative));`

If you've got different images for different locales, you could include the image name/path in a resources file and then create them from there.

Alternatively if you have a set of default images and will then have some user-added ones, and you'd like to iterate over all of those, you could write your defaults from your Images folder into IsolatedStorage at first start-up. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for details on using IsolatedStorage. You can iterate over directories and files within the apps IsolatedStorageFile (see the [methods available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path) 
{
     photos.Add(new Photo {FileName = file, PhotoSource = GetImageSource(Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))});
}
```

which returns a List of the Contents of the Folder.

Path.Combine combines single strings to a full Path (So you don't need to worry about the Backslahes.

The Path Namespace is pretty underrated, i'd suggest you to take a close look to it since it will save you much time.

Comment: The question is about Windows Phone. You don't have access to the file system on Windows Phone.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. The `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is throwing an exception `Attempt to access the method failed: System.Environment.get_CurrentDirectory()`. Any ideas left? Thanks anyway.