# local XML to Listbox in c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

There are some clases:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string fullName;
        string firstName;
        string middleName;
        string lastName;
        string sex;
        string photoFilename;
        decimal gradePointAverage;

        public string FullName
        {
            set
            {
                if (fullName != value)
                {
                    fullName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return fullName;
            }
        }

...
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And:

```
        public class StudentBody : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string school;
            ObservableCollection<Student> students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            public string School
            {
...
            }
            public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
            {
                set
                {
                    if (students != value)
                    {
                        students = value;    
                    }
                }
                get
                {
                    return students;
                }
            }

            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (null != PropertyChanged)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        }
```

I'm trying to put the names of the students to listboks:

```
    ObservableCollection<StudentBody> StudentBody = new ObservableCollection<StudentBody>();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentBody));
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"XMLFile1.xml");
    StudentsList.ItemsSource = StudentBody;
```

from tnis XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentBody xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <School>El Paso High School</School>
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <FullName>Adkins Bowden</FullName>
      ...
    </Student>
    <Student>
      ...
    </Student>
    <Student>
      ...
    </Student>
  </Students>
</StudentBody>
```

But in the end I receive an error

> Could not find schema information for the element 'StudentBody'.

What am I doing wrong and how to put the data in listboks?

EDIT:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var istream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentBody));
        StudentBody StudentBody = xml.Deserialize(istream) as StudentBody; // here error
        StudentsList.ItemsSource = StudentBody.Students;
    }
}
```

error: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlSerializer.Serialize and XmlSerializer.Deserialize. XmlReader is not needed here, and probably it causes the problem.

Examples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

EDIT:

To open a file use a FileStream class, and pass it as an argument to these methods.

Quote from the above link:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
```

EDIT2 (regarding comment):

Sorry, didn't notice the WP7 tag. I believe here is an answer regarding the exception you get now:

[Windows Phone 7 : FileStream exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234035/windows-phone-7-filestream-exception)

Comment: then how can I open a file?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please, just look at the examples from the link I've provided. It's all there.

Comment: I changed the code:

`FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentBody)); //here error
StudentBody StudentBody = xml.Deserialize(fs) as StudentBody;
StudentsList.ItemsSource = StudentBody.Students;`

but now there is another error:
Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode)